# unable to solve Improperly Configuation error in django

Tags: python, django, web, crud

I am developing a crud application using django,using Class based views, Create, retrieve, details functions are working properly but update function don't here is my code snippets
kindly dont mark my question negative, i'm a beginner.

**ERROR**
[image: And here is my Error]

**views.py**

```
class Update(UpdateView):
    fields = ('age', 'email')
    models = models.CreateUser
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name='main'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$', views.Create.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Details.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Update.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'', views.UsersList.as_view(), name='allUsers'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class CreateUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:create', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

From details page i'm calling that view on a button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'mainApp/base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="jumbotron container">
<h1>Welcome to the Users detail page</h1>
    <h2>User Details</h2>
    <p>Name : {{user_details.name}}</p>
    <p>Age: {{user_details.age}}</p>
    <p>Email: {{user_details.email}}</p>
    <p>Gender: {{user_details.gender}}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'main:update' pk=user_details.pk %}">Update this</a></p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In `Update` class, you say `models`, you need to say `model`. It is a typo. At least, this is what I see.

Comment: yes you are right
Thank you.

Comment: And I suggest you to rename your classes. No hard feelings but it is painful to see the example. If I were you, I'd name `CreateUser` to `User`, `Create` to `CreateUserView`, `Update` to `UpdateUserView` etc. If you create another model named `Foo`, you are going to create the other views for it named `CreateFooView`, `UpdateFooView` etc. Keep it in a pattern.

Comment: again thank you for the suggestion i'll change them ,i'm a beginner so it will take some time to learn these conventions.